# When calculating a dihedral angle for a chemical bond, how is the direction defined? What are the most common convention?

Tags: bond

I understand the geometry and calculation of a dihedral angle, discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47059/221321). It is not clear how the direction is defined for a chemical bond.  On the [wiki page for dihedral angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle), it states that, "the dihedral angle $\phi$ is the counterclockwise angle..." between the planes $P_{123}$ and $P_{234}$ (where $P_{123}$ is defined as the plane containing atoms 1, 2, and 3 in the diagram below, and likewise for $P_{234}$).

$\hspace{45 mm}$[image: bonds]

This counterclockwise definition means that the direction of the dihedral angle is defined using the left-hand rule about the line connecting atom 2 to atom 3.  The left-hand rule is unusual in mathematics and geometry.  Alternatively, this example may be defining the directionality of $\phi$ simply so the result is a positive angle less than $180^\circ$.

I have not been able to find any chemistry standards on this.  Is there a common convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [IUPAC Gold Book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/T06406.html) states that,

> In a [Newman projection](http://goldbook.iupac.org/N04134.html) the torsion angle is the angle (having an absolute value between 0° and 180°) between bonds to two specified ([fiducial](http://goldbook.iupac.org/F02356.html)) groups, one from the atom nearer (proximal) to the observer and the other from the further (distal) atom. The torsion angle between groups A and D is then considered to be positive if the bond A-B is rotated in a clockwise direction through less than 180° in order that it may eclipse the bond C-D: a negative torsion angle requires rotation in the opposite sense.

This implies a range of -180 to 180, which is by far the most typical range used, but I certainly have seen reports ranging from 0..360, e.g., 225 degree dihedrals.

Comment: When they report a negative dihedral angle, or an angle larger than 180, there has to be some way they are determining directionality.  Otherwise the results are ambiguous.

Comment: The link you provided does describe the orientation, "In a Newman projection the torsion angle is the angle (having an absolute value between 0° and 180°) between bonds to two specified (fiducial) groups, one from the atom nearer (proximal) to the observer and the other from the further (distal) atom. The torsion angle between groups A and D is then considered to be positive if the bond A-B is rotated in a clockwise direction through less than 180° in order that it may eclipse the bond C-D: a negative torsion angle requires rotation in the opposite sense."

Comment: I am not familiar with the IUPAC Gold Book but it seem valid.  According to this definition, the wiki page is incorrect and the torsion angle is defined using the right-hand rule along the line connecting atoms 2 and 3.

Comment: My point is that despite the Gold Book, different software (or people) report different references.

Comment: This is good to note.  I think the most important point is that they use the same directionality (but maybe this is not the case).  If a positive angle is always defined using the right-hand rule about the B-C line (simplified version of the IUPAC Gold Book), converting from -60 to +300 is straightforward.  Without a common orientation, anything but 0-180 is ambiguous.